# Powershell output to PHP variable using shell_exec

Tags: php, powershell, shell-exec

I have a powershell script which outputs a video file duration. Running this script gives me the expected result.

```
$Folder = 'C:\my\path\to\folder'
$File = 'sample1_1280_720.mp4'
$LengthColumn = 27
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application 
$objFolder = $objShell.Namespace($Folder)
$objFile = $objFolder.ParseName($File)
$Length = $objFolder.GetDetailsOf($objFile, $LengthColumn)
Write-Output $Length
```

In a php file, I'm trying to save this output to a variable.

```
<?php
$var = shell_exec("powershell -File C:\my\path\to\psFile.ps1 2>&1");
echo "<pre>$var</pre>";
?>
```

The string output I get from shell_exec is the text you see when you start powershell from cmd.  *Windows PowerShell 
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.* Any suggestions on how to extract the video duration?

Comment: What happens if you add `-NoLogo` to your PowerShell command in the `shell_exec()`?

Comment: "powershell -NoLogo -File ..." - gives the same output

Comment: This suggests that something about the way `shell_exec()` is handling the command line you're passing it is ... odd. If you add code to your script to output the results to a file, does the file get created and does it contain what you expect it to?

Comment: Yes, this was my backup plan which  I've successfully tested. Piped it with `| Out-File -FilePath C:\... -Append`. The result creates a file if not exists and appends otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your PS code

```
$Folder = 'C:\my\path\to\folder'
$File = 'sample1_1280_720.mp4'
$LengthColumn = 27
$objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$objFolder = $objShell.Namespace($Folder)
$objFile = $objFolder.ParseName($File)
$Length = $objFolder.GetDetailsOf($objFile, $LengthColumn)
$Length
```

I'm able to get the file length using PS `-File` and `-Command`. I added a few other flags you may want or need. You shouldn't need to use redirection `2>&1` to get your variable from PS to PHP. It is most likely the reason you are getting the logo.

```
function PowerShellCommand($Command)
{
    $unsanitized = sprintf('powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "%s"', $Command);

    return shell_exec($unsanitized);
}

function PowerShellFile($File)
{
    $unsanitized = sprintf('powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%s"', $File);

    return shell_exec($unsanitized);
}

// Can use relative paths
echo PowerShellCommand("./psFile.ps1");
// Be sure to escape Windows paths if needed
echo PowerShellFile("C:\\my\\path\\to\\folder\\psFile.ps1");
```

Returning `$Length` in all three ways work for me

```
$Length
return $Length
Write-Output $length
```

Comment: Excellent! It was the combination of escaping the Windows path and `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` together which made it go through. I've tried them separately but not together. Thank you :)