# How to confirm URL of server with VK bot?

Tags: php, bots, vk

I'm trying to write bot for vk.com website. I wrote the basic server confirmation code, but it refused to work (means that vk.com sends me a POST request with JSON {type: 'confirmation'} after which I need to respond with my CONFIRM_KEY). The problem is that it is an error while confirmation: "HTTP response code said error".

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    define('SECRET_KEY', 'blahblahblah');
    define('CONFIRM_KEY', 'ffffff');

    if (!isset($_REQUEST))
    {
        return;
    }

    $event = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

    if (strcmp($event['secret'], SECRET_KEY) !== 0 && strcmp($event['type'], 'confirmation') !== 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    switch ($event['type'])
    {
        case 'confirmation':

            echo CONFIRM_KEY;
            break;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Make up your mind, whether you want to use constants or variables. `define($_SECRET_KEY,…)` would use the _content_ of the variable $_SECRET_KEY as the name for the constant to be defined, but you have no such variable in your script at that point.

Comment: Plus: you might want to change the values of those "secret" keys now, as anyone with an internet connection has access to them.

Comment: constants should not begin with a `$`

Comment: Duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42298608/powershell-output-to-php-variable-using-shell-exec#42300182

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell output to PHP variable using shell\_exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42298608/powershell-output-to-php-variable-using-shell-exec)

Comment: @delboy1978uk, it is even not about vk.com's API

Comment: @misorude, thanks, I edited the code, but I'm still getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I bumped into was not in the code, but in the SSL sertificate of my web server. After I added SSL created by CloudFlare everithyng start works.